# How to put a C# application on a webpage

Tags: c#, web-applications

I've been learning C# this week by building a few simple financial forms and I'd like to put them on a website, but some Google searches didn't come up with any useful information. What would be the best way to embed the applications I'm building into a website?

If it matters, I'm currently learning in C# Express, but I have access to Visual Studio Professional as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) is actually the best way of putting .NET applications on a web page. If you want more richness and interaction you could always use [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/). If you have a specific programming related question with an actual problem you are encountering you could always use [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Silverlight is obsolete. Don't use it

Answer (score 2):

I am gonna disagree Darin, and  say it's much easier to embed [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/) applications onto a web.

Silverlight can deployed on pretty much any webhosting company, while ASP.NET requires special hosting.

Comment: +1 Silverlight is what I started with. I learned most of my foundational C# knowledge from a large Silverlight project, and the learning curve to go from WPF to Silverlight (or vice versa) is miniscule.

Answer (score 2):

you can use asp.net check this video [How to Create a Web Site with Visual Studio HTML Control Tab](http://www.5min.com/Video/How-to-Create-a-Web-Site-with-Visual-Studio-HTML-Control-Tab-80721791) and this [Creating a Visual Studio Web Application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TyrefGjMMGw)